# What control can use to order and select data? C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

Basically i am looking for the top half of this.

I am using a listbox for the left side where it says All, Active, Inactive etc.
Now i need the right side, what control is that? I need something that will highlight an entire row and allow me to order (ASC and DESC) based on the column i click.

[alt text http://dl.img.qj.net/uploads/files_module/screenshots/23991_utorrent3.png](http://dl.img.qj.net/uploads/files_module/screenshots/23991_utorrent3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx)

Comment: After a lot of tweaking i got it to look similar.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the DataGridView control.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get that would be a `GridView`.  I'm fairly sure that you should be able to customize it enough to get it to look similar to the screenshot you provided.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView or ListView (ViewMode = Details).